# 'Segmentation Fault' while recoding memset

Tags: c, assembly

I started ASM a few days ago and started recoding all the simple function libc offers us like strlen, strchr or memset. I didn't have any problem until I tried recoding memset.

Here is the prototype of the C function:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

Here is my ASM code:

```
[BITS 32]

global my_memset

my_memset:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     eax, [ebp+8]
    mov     edx, [ebp+12]
    mov     ecx, [ebp+16]

myloop:
    mov     [eax], edx
    add     eax, 1
    loop    myloop

endfunc:
    mov     eax, [ebp+8]
    leave
    ret
```

And this is the main I use for my test

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *my_memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

void main(void)
{
  char test[] = "thisisatest";

  printf("%s\n", test);
  my_memset(test, 'b', 5);
  printf("%s\n", test);
}
```

I am a bit lost on the use registers, so if I did any big mistake please let me know.

**[EDIT] Main problem has been solved(no more segfaults or errors). But I still have one last -small- problem. The string I receive is 'bbbbb' when it should be 'bbbbbsatest'**

Thank you, Ephismen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you possibly using a string literal as the target for your memset? In that case, [EAX] aka *s, can point to read-only memory.

**Edit:**
Assuming `test`and `toto` are the same variable, it should really be `const char* test=` becase a string literal is read-only. Try `char test[] =` instead to create an array containign a copy of the literal.

**Edit2:**
I have a javascript problem today, so I can not add comments.

Anyway, the new problem is `mov [eax],edx` which stores 4 bytes (some of which are 0). The previous store `move [eax],dl` stored 1 byte at a time.

**Edit3:**
@stupid_idiot - I first wrote that edx is 2 bytes (confused it with dx), and fixed that before seing your comment. Honest! :-)

Comment: mov [eax],edx stores 4 bytes, but yea you are right. this is what terminates the string with 0 after last iteration. I totaly didn't realize that. using DL or DH instead of edx should fix it, don't change the braces though.

Comment: Bo Persson: ok, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to:

```
mov [eax], dl
```

This moves the *value* in the `dl` register to the *memory address* indicated by `eax`.

Comment: I tried this before giving my code but I still had the same error.

Comment: Well, does `eax` contain what you believe it should? A debugger would be your most useful tool here.

Comment: EAX does contains what I want, since if I comment the unworking line it returns me the same string.

Comment: I think you should use `mov byte ptr [eax], dl`.

Comment: @MByD: That should be implied by the use of the `dl` register. The use of `byte ptr` should only be necessary if you're moving a constant such as 0 (otherwise the assembler won't know how wide to make the memory reference).

Comment: Yes that's right but i don't think that's what MByD wanted to point out. It does quite matter how do you use the [] braces.